# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import (после сборки React js проекта с помощью Gulp и Browserify)

Tags: javascript, gulp, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babel

Создал проект. в pacakge.json указал следующие зависимости:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "gulp"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "babelify",
        {
          "presets": [
            "es2015",
            "react"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-webserver": "~0.9.1",
    "pretty-hrtime": "^1.0.1",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "watchify": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.11",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "~15.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.0-rc.2",
    "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.0.22",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^2.3.8",
    "react-breadcrumbs": "^1.3.16",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1",
    "react-notifications": "~1.3.0",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

gulpfile:

```
var babelify = require('babelify');
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('./gulp/tasks', { recurse: true });
```

gulp-конфиг:

```
var dest = './build',
  src = './src';

module.exports = {
  browserSync: {
    server: {
      // We're serving the src folder as well
      // for sass sourcemap linking
     baseDir: [dest, src]
    },
    files: [
      dest + '/**'
    ]
  },
  markup: {
    src: src + "/frontend/**",
    dest: dest
  },
  browserify: {
    // Enable source maps
    debug: true,
    // A separate bundle will be generated for each
    // bundle config in the list below
    bundleConfigs: [{
      entries: src + '/frontend/js/app.js',
      dest: dest,
      outputName: 'app.js'
    }],
    extensions: ['.js'],
  }
};
```

есть код реакт компонента:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link, hashHistory} from 'react-router'
import {Component} from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import Home from './Home';
import {NotificationContainer, NotificationManager} from 'react-notifications';


const App = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="row">
                    <b>Hello I'am reaaact!</b>
                </div>
                <div className='app-container'>
                    <hr/>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

render((<Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

собираю командой npm start,gulp собирает все нормально, однако при запуске в браузере он ругается на импорты. папка node_modules с установленными react-модулями есть, однако ощущение,что он их не видит, и не может произвести импорт нужных компонентов реакт-библиотеки. как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ннда отлаживать. Очевидно ваш сборщик не жует es6 импорты. Но насколько я понял из беглого взгляда в доки, babelify должен это отрабатывать (точно не знаю, я из секты вебпака). Вообще es6 транспилится, отваливаются только импорты?

Comment: импорты идут вначале кода,дальше я не смотрел,думал сначала с ними разобраться.за основу брал https://github.com/callemall/material-ui-browserify-gulp-example  но были внесены некоторые правки

Comment: дело в том, что задача понимания синтаксиса модулей лежит на сборщике или плагине на сборщик (browserify/babelify), задача преобразования es6 в es5 - лежит на транспилере (babel). Плюс у вас галп таски не напрямую пишутся и еще через одну прослойку. Я бы попробовал понять - что не отрабатывает. Таска на транспайл (обрушится транспиляция и импорты) или плагин на модули (обрушатся только импорты)

Comment: как в такой ситуации протестировать их?

Comment: Ну напишите какую-нибудь файлик с es6-конструкцией вроде стрелочной функции и посмотрите что в итоге в бандле. Если вместо стрелочек в бандле валидный es5 код, значит бабель сработал и копать надо в сторону неправильного использования/подключения babelify, если ничего по сути не изменил оставив стрелочки, значит транспайлер не отработал ваще и надо искать косяк в конфиге тасок

Comment: Я бы  делал так чисто отладиться, но учтите что я вообще мимо проходил, у меня на сборке другой зоопарк)

Comment: Эм... а где пробелемный таск gulp, который должен отвечать за сборку?

Comment: немного помогла переустановка нода.некотоыре импорты он читает и собирается,но импорты бутстрапа не видит..

Comment: Dmitriy Simushev вы имеете в виду файл папку гульпа-"tasks"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновите ноду до как минимум 6.4

Версии nodejs отличались у @Iga на хост машине и на виртуальной, он скомпилировал js c хост машины где версия ноды ниже и поэтому возникали различные веселые ошибки. Не все библиотеки из указанного package.json корректно собираются используя ноду версией ниже 6.4

Comment: Gulp не работает на более младших версиях? Или может какие-то из его плагинов не работают?